# Laravel 5 display proper stacktrace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am not able to get a proper stack trace in Laravel 5, so that I can figure out where exactly is the error. As seen in the image below I am getting a random PHP filename.

How do I get the exact filename?

[image]

Comment: Can you check in your vendor directory if this file exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a random filename, it's the filename of a view that was rendered by Blade, the templating engine that Laravel uses. So the syntax error is in one of your views. You can find the file in `storage/framework/views` and you'll find the error on line 1.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out!!.